# Dictionary type input in the VSTS Build/Release Task

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have to create a VSTS Build/Release task extension which takes a dictionary as the input type.

I need to pass n number of parameters to the task and also the parameter name and the parameter value should be given dynamically (while configuring the CI and CD).

Is there any input type which is similar to the Variable section where we can specify the Key-Value pair and also we can add n number of variables.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Azure RG task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceGroupDeploymentV2/task.json) which has a key value input. See the `overrideParameters` input, it has a special editor extension.

EDIT: [search for editorExtension](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/search?p=4&q=editorExtension&unscoped_q=editorExtension) and you will find more examples of grids.
[image]

Comment: Hope this resolve my problem. I will check and let you know. Thanks

Comment: My suggestion is to try all the editor extensions and see if it serves your purpose or not. Ideally there should be a generic editor extension for keyvalue pair